# How can I access two Cassandra rows as inputs to a UDF?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Like the title, In CASSANDRA, I'm trying to access 2 different row values belonging to different columns at the same time to perform an operation (like addition).

Elaboration: Let's say I have 3 columns and some N rows ->

```
 row_id | start | end
--------+-------+-----
      1 |     3 |   7
      2 |     9 |  11
      3 |     11|  19
      4 |     22|  30
```

I want to subtract the `end` value in 1st row with `start` value in the next consecutive row.

Any Idea how may I approch this in cassandra ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do this in Cassandra.

Partitions (records) are distributed randomly across the cluster and are not sorted in the way you think it should be in a table. Your idea of "next consecutive row" will be completely different to the way data in a table is stored.

Your use case is more analytics rather than OLTP so you're better off using an ETL software like Spark. Cheers!